last date in sql
How do one write a SQL query to state the last payment date **only **and  eliminate all known date in table



ITEM
DATE
BUYER




BALL
AUGUST 5
JOHN


BALL
AUGUST 9
BOMA


KITE
JUNE 2
KEAN


KITE
JUNE 4
RAY



From the Above illustration ,we want to see last date only



ITEM
DATE
BUYER




BALL
AUGUST 9
BOMA


KITE
JUNE 4
RAY




Dates are seemingly strings and don't have year component. Is "DECEMBER 31" always considered later than "JANUARY 1"?

If you use row_number analytic function (other possible options might be rank or dense_rank) to find only the latest row per each item and date value, then - in the final step - fetch only that "latest" row.
Sample data:
SQL> with test (item, datum, buyer) as
  2    (select 'BALL', date '2024-08-05', 'JOHN' from dual union all
  3     select 'BALL', date '2024-08-09', 'BOMA' from dual union all
  4     select 'KITE', date '2024-06-02', 'KEAN' from dual union all
  5     select 'KITE', date '2024-06-04', 'RAY'  from dual
  6    ),

Query begins here:
  7  temp as
  8    (select item, datum, buyer,
  9       row_number() over (partition by item order by datum desc) rn
 10     from test
 11    )
 12  select item, datum, buyer
 13  from temp
 14  where rn = 1;

ITEM DATUM      BUYER
---- ---------- -----
BALL 09.08.2024 BOMA
KITE 04.06.2024 RAY

SQL>


I presumed that date values are real dates, not strings ("August 5"). If you really have strings, then you'll first have to transform them into valid date values, and then apply the rest of logic.
